# display webpart title based on variation

Tags: 2013, 2010

I have webpart properties called `EnglishTitle` and `FrenchTitle` for english and french variations. Currently when rendering pages, SharePoint displays `Title` first and I am changing that to `English title` or `French title` based on variation after the webpart properties get loaded.

Is there a way to ask the page not to use the `Title` property and show the title based on variation?

Comment: Can you post some code!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the SharePoint object model allows to know the variation where the loading page is. Please, look for Variations class in Publishing namespace, https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.variations.aspx